# ajax call is not responding

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax for retrieving data from my remote server when i am posting the ajax url directly in the address bar of browser, i am getting the data but when i am doing ajax call to that url in javascript file , it is showing  error.I am pasting my code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
url:"http://www.appitechture.com/api/index.php?action=getContactDetails&id=96",
type:'get',
datatype:'json',
success:function OnSuccess(data , status){
  alert(data);
   } ,

error: function OnError(request , status , error){
        alert('error');
      }
 });
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="images"></div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

so please if any one knows its solution please tell me.

Thank's
puneet

Comment: change to `datatype: 'jsonp'`

Comment: If it is not the same domain, you need to use JSONP (JSON with padding). jQuery.getJSON can help you with this.

Comment: it displays the requested data if I run your code on www.appitechture.com, but I get a cross-domain restriction error if I run it somewhere else, like Bogdan got. so the code is working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Are you trying to do a crossdomain AJAX request? Bad idea, read this article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

If it is not the same domain, you need to use JSONP (JSON with padding). This is due to Same Orgin Policy, as Bogdan Burim states.

[jQuery.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) can help you with this in a easy way. It will include a script tag like this on your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://example.com/jsonp?callback=parseResponse">
</script>
```

You will also need to change the response of the remote server to include the callback var like this:

```
parseResponse({"bar": "foo", "foo2": "bar2"});
```

You can also have a look at [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net):

> easyXDM is a Javascript library that enables you as a developer to
>   easily work around the limitation set in place by the Same Origin
>   Policy, in turn making it easy to communicate and expose javascript
>   API’s across domain boundaries.

[Wikipedia have a nice article about JSONP.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)